# Does anyone have a good example of posting a form with ajax using a backbone model?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am trying to find a working example of form posting with ajax and backbone, does anyone have a good example?

Answer (score 0):

When your Backbone.Model has defined property `url` or `urlRoot` the invocation of its [save()](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-save) method leads to sending an AJAX request to the server at that url.
If the model is new (Backbone.Model.isNew()) then the HTTP **POST** method is used, otherwise method **PUT**.

So all you need is to initialize your model properties with your form's values and save the model.